# Oracle : Error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function in Oracle Join Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Given two tables, City and Country whose description are given below. Print the name of all continents (key: Country.Continent) along with the average City population rounded down to nearest integer.

PS #1: City.CountryCode and Country.Code is same key. 
PS #2: Countries without cities should not be included in output.

```
City

 Field           Type     

 ID               int(11)  
 Name            char(35)    
 CountryCode      char(3)  
 District         char(20) 
 Population        int(11) 

Country    

Field        Type      

 Code           char(3)     
 Name          char(52)    
 Continent      char(50)  
 Region          char(26)   
 SurfaceArea     float(10,2)
 IndepYear      smallint(6) 
 Population      int(11)     
 LifeExpectancy  float(3,1)  
 GNP             float(10,2) 
 GNPOld          float(10,2) 
 LocalName      char(45)   
 GovernmentForm char(45)    
 HeadOfState     char(60)   
 Capital         int(11)    
 Code2           char(2)
```

I tried select avg(C.Population) from Country Cy join  City C on(C.CountryCode=Cy.Code) group by Cy.Continent ;

And

select avg(C.Population) ,Cy.Continent from  Country Cy join  City C on(C.CountryCode=Cy.Code);

But it is giving me an error

> ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Why is this tagged `sql-server` when the error is obviously `oracle`?

Comment: edited .. I am new to this forum ..

Comment: i would think you need to add GROUP BY cy.continent to the end of your code

Comment: Yes I have had tried it ..and I edited my question .. I have had posted one of all those queries which I tried .. And by the way I dont know why my question got a down-vote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have to add cy.continent to the select statement of your first try when you group by Cy.continent.

Try something like that (floor is for the "round it down to the nearest integer" - part):

```
SELECT floor(AVG(City.population)),Country.continent FROM City JOIN Country ON City.CountryCode = Country.Code
GROUP BY Country.continent;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select Country.Continent, Round(avg(City.Population),0)
from City, Country
where City.CountryCode = Country.Code 
group by Country.Continent ;
```